# How to get the last month's data for a quarter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create an SSRS report that has a data matrix that can be grouped monthly, quarterly, or annually. I am able to correctly group my data monthly, but I run into issues when trying to group it by anything else.

Here is a sample data set:

```
Account #     BillingDate     DateActivated      Balance
1             1/1/16          1/1/16             $10,000
1             2/1/16          1/1/16             $9,000
1             3/1/16          1/1/16             $9,500
1             4/1/16          1/1/16             $7,000
1             5/1/16          1/1/16             $4,000
1             6/1/16          1/1/16             $1,000
```

**When I am grouping quarterly, I only want the last month of the quarter's data.** For instance, for Q1 I would want the $9,500 balance and ignore the $10,000 and $9,000 balances. However, my grouping is summing them all up and giving me $28,500.

---

Desired Results

Monthly Report:

```
                       DateActivated 1/1/16
BillingDate 1/1/6      $10,000
BillingDate 2/1/6      $9,000
BillingDate 3/1/6      $9,500
BillingDate 4/1/6      $7,000
BillingDate 5/1/6      $4,000
BillingDate 6/1/6      $1,500
```

Quarterly Report:

```
                       DateActivated Q1
BillingDate Q1         $9,500
BillingDate Q2         $1,000
```

I have been trying to use a subquery, but haven't gotten on working.

Edit: I am using a simple query to get the results above:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, BillingDate, DateActivated, Balance
FROM TestTable
```

Comment: wouldn't you need 2 rows? one from 3/1/16 and the other from 6/1/16?

Comment: Correct, for the quarterly example I left off the Q2 BillingDate row. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query you're currently working with? It seems like you'd just need to group by quarter, where the month is the max of the group.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be a simple formula like:

```
=sum(switch(month(Fields!BillingDate.value) = 3 ,Balance ,
 month(Fields!BillingDate.value) = 6 ,Balance ,
month(Fields!BillingDate.value) = 9 ,Balance ,
month(Fields!BillingDate.value) = 12 ,Balance,
 month(Fields!BillingDate.value) =  month(@ParameterThruDate),Balance))
```

and matrix group

```
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields.BillingDate.value)
```

Comment: I run into the potential issue of not having a complete quarter (i.e. the most up to date record is the November, meaning checking December would give me null)

Comment: On second though I think this might work. The numbers look correct, just need the handle the case of an incomplete quarter. Any ideas?

Comment: i edited formula should work for incomplete quarter. you can use today() instead of parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create two matrixes like the following:

**Monthly report:**

[image]

**Quarterly Report:**

[image]

The Quarter row group can be calculated using this expression:

```
=DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields!BillingDate.Value)
```

To get the Quarter use:

```
="BillingDate Q" & DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields!BillingDate.Value)
```

To get the last Balance value use:

```
=SUM(
IIF(Fields!BillingDate.Value=MAX(Fields!BillingDate.Value),Fields!Balance.Value,0
))
```

Also consider to create a parent row group by Account.

This is the result:

[image]

I've created a dummy dataset with incomplete data for Q4 (no data innovember and december). It shows the octuber data if november or december are not present.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error with the last part. I don't think I have have two equal signs can I?

If I remove the equal sign before the IIF I get a rsAggreateofAggregate error.

Comment: @ferensilver, yes, I mispelled the expression.

Comment: I get no results for my last quarter. I don't need to group on the account. It honestly doesn't need to be in the query either. I only had it in there to help illustrate the data.

Comment: @ferensilver, What is the last quarter in your data? The rest of the quarters are calculated correctly? Do you have multiple balance values per BillingDate?

Comment: I have incomplete data for Q4 (October has completed, but November and December's data is incomplete). I have one balance per account per billing date. I tried recreating your example above in a simple matrix to reproduce the errors, but am getting the aggregate error. Any ideas? https://i.imgur.com/ugrY8tj.png

Comment: @ferensilver, In my example I used BillingDate in the Rows Group as you pointed as the desired results in your OP, you are using it in the column groups though. Try recreating my example.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue, https://i.imgur.com/neMUZLf.png. I'll keep trying. I must be doing something wrong. I had it working before, I think.

Comment: @ferensilver, edit the BillingDate row group using this expression `DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,Fields!BillingDate.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is always best to have the sql do the heavy lifting and keep the SSRS RDLs pretty simple. I would update your query to only return the records you need based on a @period_type parameter. This example assumes your data is already grouped monthly as your sample data shows. If this is not the case, let me know and I can update this example:

```
if @period_type = 1 -- monthly
    select
        AccountNumber,
        -- convert BillingDate to text so the data type matches the Quarter strings
        convert(varchar(10),BillingDate,101) as BillingDate
        DateActivated,
        Balance
    from TestTable

if @period_type = 2 -- quarterly
    select
        AccountNumber,
        BillingDate
        DateActivated,
        Balance
    from (
         select
             AccountNumber,
             'Q' + cast(datepart(quarter,BillingDate) as char(1)) as BillingDate
             DateActivated,
             Balance,
             row_number() over(partition by datepart(quarter,BillingDate)
                               order by BillingDate desc) keep_this_1
         from TestTable
         ) tt
    where keep_this_1 = 1
```